# select does not work in android 2.2

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

In my app i've a select button which shows multiple options when i click on it....It works well with android 4.1, but in android 2.2 when i click on it there's no effect so the options couldn't be selected....

```
<section class="fullContainer">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="descriptionRedeem"></div> 
        <div class="redeemContent"> 
            <form id="form_SNOWFLYGIFTCARDS">
            <p>Select a gift card</p>
            <select name="giftName" id="giftId">
                       <option value="">Select</option>
                       <option value="1001">Toys</option>
                       <option value="1002">Cosmetics</option>
                       <option value="1003">Cloths</option> 
                    </select>
        <input  type="button" value="Submit" name="submit_snowfly_gc" onclick="submitRedeemPoint()" >   <br>                                                                               
                <input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="_eventId_Cancel" >
            </form>
        </div>
         </div> 
    </section>
```

Comment: That's a great piece of information, what's the question? I guess it's "How can I make a select element work in Android 2.2?"

Comment: scrap the project and go native?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but its worth a try.

```
<input  type="button" value="Submit" name="submit_snowfly_gc" onclick="submitRedeemPoint()" />
<br />                                                                               
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="_eventId_Cancel" />
```

I'm assuming that old android browsers were strict enough to ignore not-well-formed HTML.